# Cannot accquire data from form in html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to post the data in the form and get it in the server, finally jump to the chat.html page. The client data is below

```html
<form action="chat.html" method="POST">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="username"
                            id="username"
                            placeholder="Enter username..."
                            required
                        />

                        <input
                        type="text"
                        name="room"
                        id="room2"
                        placeholder="Enter room name..."
                        required
                        disabled = "disabled"
                        />
...
</form>
```

Server end

```html
app.post("chat.html", (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.body);
});
```

I hope the data in form could be received by server and the client could jump to chat.html page. However the problem **Cannot POST /chat.html** occurred. How could i solve this? I try to use

```
<form action="/chat" method="POST">
```

The data could be received but the page can't jump.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the form action as a route and use the same route in the back as well.

In the form;

```
<form action="/chat" method="POST"> ...
```

Backend;

```
// render the chat.html
app.get("/chat",(request,response)=>{ response.render("chat.html")});
// post request in /chat route
app.post("/chat", (request, response) => {console.log("form posted")});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to make post request .

like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/chat',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```